# How to apply a Laravel Eloquent where() condition on both parent and child (hasMany() relationship)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-eloquent-resource

I have a Laravel Eloquent Model called `EmailList` and a model called `Subscriber`.
I defined the following hasMany relationship on the EmailList.

```php
    public function subscribers() {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscriber::class);
    }
```

This relationship works fine.

I now want to apply a `where()` condition on the parent and a `where()` condition on the child.

For example, I have two `EmailList`s, with a property `id` and a property called `listname` ("List A" and "List B"). My `Subscriber` model has four relevant properties: `id`, `name`, `email` and `email_list_id`.

Problem: **I want to take all subscribers from a certain list, e.g. 'List A', and filter the subscribers with `$query`** (search functionality with Livewire)**.**

In order to accomplish this, I came up with the following code:

```php
EmailList::where('listname', $listname)->first()
                                    ->subscribers()
                                    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                                    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
                                    ->paginate(50) //or get(), if you like
```

This code partially worked, because the subscribers were indeed filtered, but not the EmailList. In other words, I just searched all subscribers, rather than the subscribers on a specific list.

After a lot of searching I figured out that I should perhaps use a `whereHas()`, but when I tried that, it gave me only EmailLists and not Subscribers.

It'd be great if someone could help me filter this. Perhaps it's peanuts for an experienced developer, but it would help me a lot!

**Update:**
After seeing the answer by EricLandheer, I realised that (of course) I also have the EmailList id. Perhaps that makes it a little bit simpler, so that you can use find() instead of a where()->first() clause. (I use first() because the ‘listname’ is unique and I only want one instance. Is that correct?)

Comment: try this   $search=$this->search;
   $data= EmailList::where('listname', $listname)->with('subscribers')->whereHas('subscribers',function ($query)use($search){
        $query->where('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
    })->where(function ($query)use($search){
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
    })->paginate(50);

Comment: Hey John, thanks! Could you perhaps put it in an answer? I’ll test it and let you know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your code only returns the first `EmailList`. Did you that purposely, or do you only want the first `EmailList` that has the `$listname`?

Here is a solution using [Eager loading with constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) that overrides the `subscribers` relation with a callback. The result should be all `EmailLists` with the `$listname` and the matching subscribers with the search.

```
EmailList::where('listname', $listname)
    ->with('subscribers', function($query) {
        return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
    })->get();
```

**Regarding question update**

Indeed, using Listname is fine. If it is unique, no problem. You can use `find()` with an ID to, which is preferable if you're thinking of changing the name of the `EmailList` at a later stage.

Perhaps a more elegant / readable solution would be:

```
$emailList = EmailList::firstWhere('listname', $listname);

$emailList->subscribers = $emailList->subscribers()
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
    ->get();
```

You could refactor the search to a model / service if you are using it in more places:

```
// EmailList model

public function subscribers() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subscriber::class);
}

public function searchSubscribers(string $search): Collection 
{
    return $this->subscribers()
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->search.'%')
        ->get();
}
```

**Final code**

```
$emailList = EmailList::firstWhere('listname', $listname);

$emailList->subscribers = $emailList->searchSubscribers($this->search);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, I’ll check it and let you know!

Comment: I have updated my initial answer, with a cleaner approach in my opinion. I did not test it, but it is pretty straightforward I think. Consider refactoring the `search()` function to a separate class (like a UserSearchService), in case the function is used in other classes as well.

Comment: Hey Eric, thanks a lot for your answer. I went with the cleaner solution